# How to using BUILDMCS and propagate an FMID to another SMP/E zone

Tags: mainframe, zos

We've just upgraded to z/OS V2.2 which comes with Java 8. We have a product that doesn't work with Java 8 and so we want to take Java 7 out of out z/OS V1.13 zone and put it into it's own zone.

I've done a BUILDMCS for Java 7, defined a new zone, added the necessary DD DEFS (as identified by the BUILDMCS) and received HJVB710 into the new zone. SMP built the relfiles using the datasets specified by the FROMDS parms of my MCS.

Thinking about APPLYing HJVB710 to my target zone and I realise that applying it will simply copy from the relfiles into my target libraries, which are the same libraries that the relfiles were built from and which already have all of the Java 7 elements in them.

Question - when using BUILDMCS to move an FMID from one SMP/E environment to another, should I specify a new set of target libraries? If not, should I then delete the FMID from the 'old' SMPE/E environment to prevent maintenance being applied to it, causing the target libraries to be updated and thus invalidating the information in the 'new' CSI?

Comment: There's a ton of sysprogs on the IBM-MAIN mailing list (which can be viewed with google groups, but best to post to from the mailserver for maximum coverage).

Comment: @BillWoodger I know there aren't many z/OS people here, but I like the moderated question/comment format. Some of the other mainframe forums can get a bit...superior. (*cough*enrico*cough*)